# Responsive flex box design with sticky header

Tags: css, sticky, flexbox

I am having problems designing a sticky header for my responsive layout site which uses flex box. I found this fiddle which almost solves my problem, but not quite: http://jsfiddle.net/RnBhH/2/

1. How can I make the header element height fit the content in the header since the height is different depending on device viewport width?
2. Provided #1 is solved, how can I make the article and the footer to be scrollable while the variable height header sticky to the top?

   ```
   html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
   }
   body {
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   }
   header {
    flex: 1;
    background:red;
   }
   article {
    flex: 8;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background:green;
   }
   footer {
    flex: 1;
    background:blue;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 11):

It's a little hard to catch what are you trying to do, but I have modified the fiddle to this

http://jsfiddle.net/Xpvj4/

The idea is to have just two main flexed elements `header` and `.content` and put both `article` and `footer` into the `.content`.

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  background:red;
}
.content {
    flex: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
article {
    background:green;
}
footer {
    height: 40px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a div and take both article & footer inside it.
Name class ="scrollable" to that div. & Apply this CSS :

```
.scrollable{
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: But what should the value of the flex property for header and .scrollable be? I want the height of the header to be dynamic. Should I not use flex box at all?